# How do I make the bot respond to my order in telegram Finances Stock?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, stock

I am creating a bot for telegram and I would like to add a function. For example .. By writing `/u` in the group stock send the price

```py
/u msft
/u gold
```

and send the last price.
Finally, I also wanted to get the automatic update. Only function when writing to group `/u msft`.
Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

```py
def telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_message):
    bot_token='xxxx389537:AAGDTaYAz-htwJV_6n9UEMsce3SgNu7c6XE'
    bot_chatID='-xxxx43831'
    send_text='https://api.telegram.org/botxxxx389537:AAGDTaYAz-htwJV_6n9UEMsce3SgNu7c6XE/sendMessage?chat_id=-537743831&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message
    response=requests.get(send_text)
    return response.json()
test=telegram_bot_sendtext("Grupo de asesoramiento. Respondo de 11:30 - 18:00")
print(test)
Price= ''

    def getStock():
     bot_token='xxxx389537:AAGDTaYAz-htwJV_6n9UEMsce3SgNu7c6XE'
     bot_chatID='-xxxx43831'
     response= "Let me fetch Latest quote for you \n"
     symbol='ITC.NS'
     aapl=pdr.get_data_yahoo(symbol,  start=datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 14), 
                          end=datetime.datetime(2040, 12, 14))
     price=(aapl["Close"][0]).round(2)
     price=str(price)
     price="Current price for "+symbol+ " is "+price
     price=str(price.encode('utf-8','ignore'),errors='ignore')
     send_text='https://api.telegram.org/botxxxx389537:AAGDTaYAz-htwJV_6n9UEMsce3SgNu7c6XE/sendMessage?chat_id=-xxxx43831&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + price
     response=requests.get(send_text)
     print(response)

    import threading
while True:
    getStock()
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: What output does your current code have?

Comment: In my code dont have any input or that's what I see about how little I understand

import requests
import time
import schedule
import datetime
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import yfinance as yf

Comment: I'm not asking about your code's INPUT, I'm asking about its OUTPUT. What does your code currently do that's different from the expected result?

Comment: Automatically delivers the last price without being called (
Every 60 seconds)... What I want to do is call the group / u <stock> and give the last price

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.